# Implementing changes via script

Tags: script, shell-script

Learning stage of understanding script. I have to make these below change on every new system. So I created these script, unfortunately it isn't working.

I want to understand that if the user input is read and kept in a variable how can I use it again after some time. Like in this script I have asked the user for their input `Is this a DNS Server` and `what is the rev of the server`.

```
#!/bin/bash


    echo -n "Is this a DNS Server [y n]?"
    read command

    if [ $command = n ]
            then
                    yum -y install dnsmasq
                    yum -y install net-snmp net-snmp-utils
    elif [ $command = n ]
            then
                    echo $command

    else
            echo "DNS Package installation should be excluded"

    fi

cat <<EOF>>  scriptos.sh
!/bin/sh


export rev="avi"
export DNS_FLG="Y"
export DNS_FLG="N"
EOF


echo -n "what is the rev of the server"
read rev

if [ $rev = y ]
        then
                echo export LOC=$rev
if [ $rev = N ]
        then
                echo export DNS_FLG="Y"

if [ $rev = Y ]
        then
                echo export DNS_FLG="Y"

fi


echo "what your GW"
read GW
echo "what is your NW"
read NW

echo 192.168.0.0/16 via ${GW}  >  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1
echo ${NW} via ${GW} >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1


/etc/init.d/network restart
```

This script is not working because of this bellow error.

```
[root@centos6 ~]# ./script
Is this a DNS Server [y n]?y
DNS Package installation should be excluded
what is the rev of the servery
./script: line 57: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: The first errors are caused by the malformatted expression in the if-statement. Please add your `n` inside quotes. (The `$command` can also be quoted in case there might be a whitespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Programming languages are picky about syntax. In sh/bash, the `[` works as a standalone *command* (unlike parens in most other languages), so it needs to be separated by spaces, as well as all its arguments. Therefore:

```
if [ "$command" = y ]; then
    …
elif [ "$command" = n ]; then
    …
fi
```

Second: Many of your condition blocks are missing the closing `fi`. It's **always** `if…then…fi`.

Third: Some of your prompts check for lowercase `y/n`, others check for uppercase `Y/N`. You should consistently accept the same inputs everywhere. For example:

```
# option 1 – make the variable lower-case

if [ "${command,,}" = y ]; then
    …

# option 2 (bash-only) – use extended match

if [[ $command == @(y|Y) ]]; then
    …

# option 3 (sh/bash) – use 'case' alternatives

case $command in
    y|Y)
        … ;;
    n|N)
        … ;;
esac
```

Fourth: `<<EOF` redirects *input*. The `echo` command does not take any input (only command line). You would want to use **`cat <<EOF`** instead, and don't forget to finish the text with an `EOF` line.

Finally, make sure to put the `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` header at the top of all your scripts.

Comment: Grawity I have modified the question as per you suggestion. But still its getting error on line 57.

Comment: I am able to see the file created `scriptos.sh`  its asking me `echo -n "what is the rev of the server"`  but when I enter the any thing it gives me error `./script: line 57: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: See points #1 and #2; you haven't fixed those in the 2nd half yet.